# Android Studio stack trace referencing imaginary directory

Tags: android

I am trying to debug a signed apk of my app but the stack trace references a directory that doesn't exist.

```
2021-07-06 20:54:54.460 11377-11377/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.germsoft.bizqrd, PID: 11377
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at c.b.a.b.b.a(Contact.java:137)
```

[image: apk directory]

As you can see from the photo, the directory c.b.a.b.b.a doesn't exist so I don't know where to start debugging this. Am I missing something?

Comment: Fixed the image. Please follow the right format so the image will appear.